# Find element after hovering over the mouse Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, iframe

Hi there I'm working on a script but I was unable to find the element
I'm using css selectors and x paths to find element seems there is iframe which is not letting me grab element please have a look on the picture [image: Gmail Compose Box]

Elements I'm trying to grab are in the compose message box When I write the email and hover my mouse over it.
I'm trying to grab image src and Example@gmail.com  which are highlighted

code is working ok till Hovering over the element for hovering I'm using

```
hover = ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(element)
hover.perform()
```

but after that I'm unable to find the elements

```
            try:
            driver.switchTo().frame('__HC_94253229')
        except:
            print("error in frame")
        try:
            image_link = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#yDmH0d > c-wiz > div.DYLA1c.q8ixdb > div > span > div.jWy8Pe > div > div.uqcMFc').get_attribute('href')
            print(image_link)
        except:
            print("error in image")

        try:
            name = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#yDmH0d > c-wiz > div.DYLA1c.q8ixdb > div > span > div.jWy8Pe > div > div.Y3Snyd > div.YysZRb > span').text
            print(name)
        except:
            print("error in name")
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out

```
iframe = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//iframe[@name='__HC_94253229']")
driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)
```

after using above code I finally able to grabe the iframe elements